# Renaming kafka connector as a force restart connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have this relatively simple postgres source `my-connector`, running as a `debezium/connect:latest` docker container.

```
{"name":"my-connector","config":
{"connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
"database.user":"postgres",
"database.dbname":"postgres",
"slot.name":"my_slot",
"tasks.max":"1",
"database.server.name":"postgres",
"database.port":"5432",
"schema.whitelist":"public",
"database.hostname":"postgres",
"database.password":"mypass",
"name":"my-connector",
"tasks":[{"connector":"my-connector","task":0}],
"type":"source"}
```

If I try to restart with `curl -i -X POST localhost:8083/connectors/my-connector/restart`, I get a successfull return message:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Mon, 22 Mar 2021 11:39:59 GMT
Server: Jetty(9.4.20.v20190813)
```

However, I do not get the expected behaviour of the connector pushing the data in the postgres tables to the respective kafka topics. As a workaround, I could create a new connector with the same configurations and change it's name to say `my-connector2`, I would obtain the expected behaviour. Therefore, I would just like to ask if there is an more elegant to restart the connector to achieve the expected behaviour?

Comment: Did you check the status of the first connector? Sounds like it's not actually running

Comment: Yes, what exactly do you want to achieve? What is the  content of the log of the first connector?

Comment: the first connector is running (according to /connectors/my-connector endpoint) before performing a restart. I want the log files in the /kafka/data/tables* folders filled with the data present in the postgres tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour:

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/tutorial.html#restarting-kafka-connect-service

> The Kafka Connect service starts, connects to Kafka, reads the
> previous service’s configuration, and starts the registered connectors
> that will resume where they last left off.

What you want to do is to reset the offset:

https://debezium.io/documentation/faq/#how_to_remove_committed_offsets_for_a_connector

Comment: thanks [senjin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7451566/senjin-hajrulahovic), I was in need of the concept of tombstone messages! For more information on tombstone messages, please refer to Robin Moffatt's [introduction to tombstone messages](https://rmoff.net/2020/11/03/kafka-connect-ksqldb-and-kafka-tombstone-messages/).